# Loki System text malformed

Tags: release-loki, graphic-drivers, greeter

I have installed the latest Elementary OS Loki Release (not a BETA version). Sometimes when the system wakes up from sleep, after I log in, I see this behavior of the system. Almost all the text is gone as you can see in the picture: The Application Menu, System Settings, Notifications bubbles, Terminal, Files, (all apps). The problem is solved when I reboot the OS.

P.S. I mention that I installed elementary tweaks from [this github project](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks), but I don't think that it has to do with this bug.

So how can I solve this problem? Is it a known bug that will be solved in some future updates? Can it be a graphics driver issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the last updates the bug seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on ubuntu.  Does ctrl-alt-f2 then ctrl-alt-f7 bring it back quicker than a reboot?  Sorry i don't have a permanent fix.

Comment: No. As I know the comand `CTRL+ALT+F<1 to 6>` brings to front a console screen. When I switch to the console screen I see only a black screen. No text shown. No prompt for login. But if I switch back to the GUI screen (`CTRL+ALT+F7`) for less then a second I see the text on the console, prompting me to login then it switches me to the GUI. I tried to log in the black screen, but it doesn't make the text visible.